# GitLab + Composer + Private Repo + SSH only

Tags: ssh, composer-php, gitlab, repository

So I have made a composer package and I have a GitLab cloning URL for it

`git@gitlab.mycompany.hu:composer-packages/another-package.git`

On our GitLab server we have 2FA enabled and forced and HTTPS cloning is also disabled, only SSH is allowed. How can I tell composer in `composer.json` how to clone the repository?

I've tried:

```
repositories": [
    { "type":"gitlab", "url": "git@gitlab.mycompany.hu:composer-packages/another-package.git" }
  ],
.
.
.
"require": {
  ...
  "composer-packages/another-package": "1.0",
  ...
"config": {
  ...
  "gitlab-domains": ["gitlab.mycompany.hu"],
  "gitlab-token": {"gitlab.mycompany.hu": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR"}
```

For token, I have tried both access token for the user that was generated and also a deploy token generated for the project. None for them worked. All I get is:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                           
  Invalid credentials for 'https://gitlab.mycompany.hu/api/v4/projects/omposer-packages%2Fanother-package', aborting.
```

Help me please.

Comment: Any reason to not use `"type":"git"`? It should clone repo through ssh and ssh keys should be used for authentication.

Comment: If I recall, the authentication was not right with that type. Never mind it now, the project is closed and I'm too busy to re-open it. (ﾟ￢ﾟ)

Comment: This is going to be fixed in the next release of gitlab 16.4 (the current version is 16.3), with feature flag composer_use_ssh_source_urls enabled https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/119739

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `"type": "git"` in composer repositories section allows you to do the clone with SSH and 2FA enabled.

<sub>Answer based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56040329/gitlab-composer-private-repo-ssh-only/64335011#comment112778224_56040329)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

No solution. (︶︹︺)

It works only if we create a new user and disable 2FA for it's login and we use it's access token to clone the repository. Since this would go against out company polity, we disbanded the whole idea and integrated the composer package into our main project.

Answer (score -2):

I was helped by removing from ~ / .config / composer / auth.json the key for the repository registered there, from which you are pulling the package. After deleting, I ran the composer update command, re-entered it (as if for the first time) - the access token was created again in the repository and registered in auth.json - everything worked as before

Comment: The goal is to use SSH keys, not access tokens, to clone the repo.